# ¿como contar el tiempo mientras se escribe en un input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo este código

```
var timer =null;
        function interval(){


        if (timer != null)
        {
          clearInterval(timer)
          timer = null
        }

        let elem = document.getElementById("segundos");
        elem.textContent="0s!!!";

        timer = setInterval(function(){

          let elem = document.getElementById("segundos");
          elem.textContent="3s!!!";
          elem.style.color = "red";
         alert('duro mas de 3');
         clearInterval(timer);
          timer = null;
          $('#buscador').val('');
          $('#buscador').html('');
        },3000);

    }


    $('#buscador').on('input',function(){
        interval();
    });
```

Lo que quiero hacer es contar el tiempo cuando se presiona una tecla, por ejemplo si escribo en el input: h (que cuente 3 segundos si se pasa de 3 segundos hacer algo)si no pasa de 3 segundos entonces que se reinicie la cuenta y así sucesivamente no se si me explique bien, no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Listo actualizo el código me funciono así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puede hacer. En este caso cada vez que el usuario presiona una tecla, se reinicia la cuenta regresiva. En caso contrario, si llega a 0 (cero), muestra un mensaje "Perdiste". Saludos!

```js
var control = setInterval(initCount,1000);
var segundos=3;

function initCount(){
 let elem = document.getElementById("segundos");
 segundos = parseInt(elem.textContent);
 segundos = segundos-1;
 elem.textContent=segundos;
 //si se termina el tiempo...
 if(segundos==0){
  // Finalizamos el "juego"
  endGame();
  }
}
function endGame(){
  let elem = document.getElementById("segundos")
  elem.textContent="Perdiste!!!";
  elem.style.color = "red";
  clearInterval(control);
 }
// cada vez que se ingresa un caracter en el input, se reinicia el contador.
function resetCount(){
  document.getElementById("segundos").textContent=3;
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="resetCount();"></textarea>
Tiempo restante: <span id="segundos">3</span>
```

Comment: en esta parte clearInterval(control); se deberia de reiniciar no?
es que al momento de yo escribir 2 palabras se reinicia y 2 veces hace lo mismo, y si escribo 3 palabras 3 veces hace lo mismo

Comment: Claro, osea lo que hace es detener el bucle en el cual se está ejecutando `initCount()`. mmm tal vez yo te entendí mal. Pensé que la idea era esa.Cada vez que se presiona una tecla se reinicia el contador (siempre y cuando no se hayan pasado los 3 segundos)

Comment: no, si esa es la idea que cuando yo presione una tecla tenga 3 segundos para seguir escribiendo si se pasa de los 3 segundos pues ya hace algo

Comment: listo gracias amigo